# How to access css or js from public folder in Rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I migrated my application from *Rails* *3.2* to *4.0*. I am having css and js in my **assets** folder and **public -> technology** folder.
Now while running the application, the css and js under public folder are not applicable.

This is my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>ABC TECHNOLOGIES</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/technology/css/vendor/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/technology/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/technology/css/colorbox.css">

  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <script src="/technology/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/technology/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
   ------------ some code ---------------
</body>
</html>
```

How to access my css / js from public folder in this layout?
Or is there any configurations I missed or made true/false in development.rb / application.rb etc; ?
This is the [link](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/06/upgrading-to-rails-4-0-from-rails-3-2-test-case-part-i-preparations-configuration-gems/) I followed.

Comment: Hm, your example works for me. Are JS and CSS available in development and not available in production? Maybe you need to update nginx's (or another webserver) config?

Comment: They are in development.

Comment: Very weird. Are you getting just 404 not found or you can't locale not even a try to load them?

Comment: I am not getting any error. My log is fine..

Comment: This is the article I followed for upgrading:  http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/06/upgrading-to-rails-4-0-from-rails-3-2-test-case-part-i-preparations-configuration-gems/